# How to Parse SOAP Response from a third party server using Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am a newbie to SOAP services, I want to extract XML from the following SOAP response which belongs to corresponding SOAP request, so my XML is contained in a String tag. I want to extract the xml from the String Tag. Please give me the solution with an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <StockQuotes>
      <Stock>
         <Symbol>STRING</Symbol>
         <Last>0.00</Last>
         <Date>N/A</Date>
         <Time>N/A</Time>
         <Change>N/A</Change>
         <Open>N/A</Open>
         <High>N/A</High>
         <Low>N/A</Low>
         <Volume>N/A</Volume>
         <MktCap>N/A</MktCap>
         <PercentageChange>N/A</PercentageChange>
         <AnnRange>N/A - N/A</AnnRange>
         <Earns>N/A</Earns>
         <P-E>N/A</P-E>
         <Name>STRING</Name>
      </Stock>
   </StockQuotes>
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811001/3224038)

You do not need any specific tool for SOAP. You just need to get info from your XML.

Comment: my soap xml response is previously what i mention the code like that only within that string tag, it just come like text                  eg:<string xmlns=""><StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>STRING</Symbol<Last>0.00</Last><Date>N/A</Date>
<Time>N/A</Time><Change>N/A</Change><Open>N/A</Open>
<High>N/A</High><Low>N/A</Low> <Volume>N/A</Volume>
<MktCap>N/A</MktCap><PercentageChange>N/A</PercentageChange>
<AnnRange>N/A - N/A</AnnRange><Earns>N/A</Earns>
<P-E>N/A</P-E><Name>STRING</Name></Stock></StockQuotes>
</string>